# Incorrect syntax near '''. code using Sum Case when

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to display a summary table with the criteria below:

1. Number of open work orders
2. Number of urgent corrective maintenance work orders > 5 days old
3. Number of routine corrective maintenance work orders > 14 days old
4. Number of routine PMs > 30 days old
5. Number of life safety PMs > 20 days old
6. Other work orders > 30 days old (not included in 2-5 above; not routine corrective, urgent corrective, or PMs)
7. Total of 2-6 (this is the # of work orders not within normal limits)
8. Number of days open Work order has been opened , if possible; today – date of oldest open work order, in # of days)
9. Number of work orders closed in last 30 days

```
SELECT vWorkOrders.DateCreated AS 'Date',

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d,vWorkOrders.DateCreated,GETDATE()) >5) AND TypeCode='CM' AND PriorityCode=’2’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Urgent Corrective Maintenance > 5 Days',

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d,vWorkOrders.DateCreated,GETDATE()) >14) AND TypeCode='CM' AND PriorityCode=’3’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Routine Corrective Maintenance > 14 Days',

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d,vWorkOrders.DateCreated,GETDATE()) >20) AND TypeCode='PM' AND PriorityCode=’7’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Life Safety Preventive Maintenance > 20 Days'

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d,vWorkOrders.DateCreated,GETDATE()) >30) AND TypeCode='PM' AND PriorityCode=’3’ AND PriorityCode=’2’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Preventive Maintenance > 30 Days',

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d,vWorkOrders.DateCreated,GETDATE()) >30) AND TypeCode<>'PM' AND TypeCode<>'CM' AND PriorityCode<>’7’ AND PriorityCode<>’3’ AND PriorityCode<>’2’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Other > 30 Days',

COUNT(*) AS 'Total',

SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCode IN ('ACTIV','PENDG’) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Active Work Orders',

SUM(CASE WHEN (vWorkOrders.CompleteDate BETWEEN CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AND DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)))) AND StatusCode=’CMPLT’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'of Work Orders closed in last 30 Days’,

SUM(CASE WHEN (DateDiff(d, GETDATE(), MIN(vWorkOrders.DateCreated)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Days Open',

FROM vWorkOrders

WHERE vWorkOrders.IDSegment = 2 OR vWorkOrders.IDSegment = 5

AND (vWorkOrders.DateCreated BETWEEN '1/1/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AND '12/31/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ' 23:59')

AND vWorkOrders.StatusCode IN ('ACTIV','PENDG')

GROUP BY vWorkOrders.DateCreated 

ORDER BY vWorkOrders.DateCreated DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a comma after

```
Life Safety Preventive Maintenance > 20 Days
```

also you have different quotation types here:

```
('ACTIV','PENDG’)
```

...and you have also different quotations here:

```
'of Work Orders closed in last 30 Days’,
```

please... try to use onlu 1 type of quotation

Comment: thank you for your quick answer but I am still getting an error "incorrect syntax near '''.   unclosed quotation mark after the character string group by vWorkOrdrs.dateCreated   ORDER BY vWorkOrders.DateCreated DESC

Comment: and youre also missing a closing parathesys in datediff near 'Days Open'